# Download server code from AWS EC2 instance to local Windows machine

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I run an AWS EC2 instance where I host all my server code. I access it through the Remote System Explorer in Eclipse. I want to download my code for later upload to an AWS CodeCommit Git repository. I feel like it can't be too complex but I'm having difficulty finding any answers in the documentation.

How should I go about doing this?

Comment: Are you able to SSH into the instance ?

Comment: Yeah I just use PuTTy

Comment: So just SSH into the server and copy the code to your Windows machine?

Comment: I'm not sure how to copy files or directories once I'm SSH'd in. What's the command?

Comment: As you are not familiar with command. Do you by any chance have Winscp on your computer?

Comment: No, but I'll download

Comment: Looks like what I need. Out of curiosity, what command would I use from the CLI to copy after SSH into the server?

Comment: I am not familiar with how cli works with Windows but if you search internet you will get it

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do it.

- Installing Dropbox on your client machine and EC2 instance is one of the easiest ways to do it.
- Install an FTP service on your EC2 host, open port 21 in the firewall and Security Group, and use your FTP client of choice on Win7 to push the data up.

**For bonus points, use SFTP instead over port 22**

- WinScp on Windows. Please follow the [link](http://codingthis.com/applications/uploading-files-to-your-amazon-ec2-server-using-winscp/) for detail instructions.

Comment: The link is dead. An official guide is here: http://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_amazon_ec2